# How can I conform to a protocol if a class has no superclass?

Tags: swift, delegates, swift2, protocols

I have a controller class (not viewController) that I want to conform to a protocol.
This controller class is not a subclass of any other class, so it has no superclass.

How can I conform to a protocol if a class has no superclass?

This is NOT working:

```
class xxxController , yyyDelegate
```

and this is NOT what is desired:

```
class xxxController : zzzSuperClasss, yyyDelegate
```

Anybody knows how it works in Swift 2.1?

UPDATE:

I forgot to write that I have tried:

```
class xxxController : yyyDelegate
```

When I do this, I get

> Type xxxController does not conform to protocol NSObjectProtocol

so I'm guessing yyyDelegate requires (in this case) that xxxController is subclass of NSObject?

Comment: `class xxxController : yyyDelegate` ?

Comment: Your edit makes your question a duplicate :)

Comment: Perfect, I will look at that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a class has a superclass, then the superclass must be listed first among the base items. When class has no superclass, protocols are listed starting from the first item.

In other words, if there is no `zzzSuperClasss`, then you could simply write

```
class xxxController : yyyDelegate
```

Swift realizes that `yyyDelegate` is a protocol, and does what you expect.

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID268) provides an example of such class:

```
protocol FullyNamed {
    var fullName: String { get }
}
class Starship: FullyNamed {
    ...
    var fullName: String {
        return (prefix != nil ? prefix! + " " : "") + name
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do this, I get "Type xxxController does not conform to protocol NSObjectProtocol", so I'm guessing yyyDelegate requires (in this case) that xxxController is subclass of NSObject?

Comment: @B-Man Yes, when you get that error message you need to extend `NSObject`, i.e. `class xxxController : NSObject, yyyDelegate`

Comment: Ok thanks I will try it out

Comment: Accepted since was the first to reply with a full answer. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You do it either by directly declaring the conformance:

```
protocol Foo { }
class Bar: Foo { }
```

.. or via extension (e.g. if you do not have the control over the class implementation, like in the cases when you get it from some library):

```
protocol Foo { }
class Bar { }
extension Bar: Foo { }
```